# Reading files from a SFTP location using Apache Beam

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I just have a few questions on achieving the $subject. I have an FTP location and I want to use a beam pipeline to read these files and do some processing. I basically want to read the file list from the FTP location every one minute and do the processing. Do you have any thoughts on this?

I have already written the pipeline for the processing part, just struggling with reading the FTP location every one minute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this with the `GenerateSequence` transform in Beam. It would be something like this:

```java
pipeline.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, standardMinutes(1))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ListAllFilesInFtpFn(serverAddress))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DownloadFilesFromFtpFn(serverAddress));
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly like this! Thanks!